# How do I solve this Python KeyError?

Tags: python, keyerror

So, I am trying to build a twitter sentiment analysis model using naive bayes. I'm getting a problem while I'm trying to preprocess my data.
Here is my code :

This is my data loading code

```
df = pd.read_csv('full-corpus.csv',
encoding='latin1',
names=['topic', 'sentiment', 'TweetId', 'TweetDate','TweetText'])
trainingData = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

This is my code for data preprocessing :

```
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from string import punctuation 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 

class PreProcessTweets:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation) + ['AT_USER','URL'])
        
    def processTweets(self, list_of_tweets):
        processedTweets=[]
        for tweet in list_of_tweets:
            
            processedTweets.append((self._processTweet(tweet['TweetText']),tweet['sentiment']))
        return processedTweets
    
    def _processTweet(self, tweet):
        tweet = tweet.lower() # convert text to lower-case
        tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'URL', tweet) # remove URLs
        tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', tweet) # remove usernames
        tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet) # remove the # in #hashtag
        tweet = word_tokenize(tweet) # remove repeated characters (helloooooooo into hello)
        return [word for word in tweet if word not in self._stopwords]
```

```
tweetProcessor = PreProcessTweets()
preprocessedTrainingSet = tweetProcessor.processTweets(trainingData)
preprocessedTestSet = tweetProcessor.processTweets(testDataSet)
```

I'm getting this keyerror

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-acc96635cf33> in <module>()
      1 tweetProcessor = PreProcessTweets()
      2 preprocessedTrainingSet = tweetProcessor.processTweets(trainingData)
----> 3 preprocessedTestSet = tweetProcessor.processTweets(testDataSet)

<ipython-input-95-05e6d1942355> in processTweets(self, list_of_tweets)
     15         for tweet in list_of_tweets:
     16 
---> 17             processedTweets.append((self._processTweet(tweet['TweetText']),tweet['sentiment']))
     18         return processedTweets
     19 

KeyError: 'TweetText'
```

Please help to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Can you include a part of your dataframe so we can try it out.

Comment: The error is at `testDataSet`, so that probably doesn't have the structure you think it does. Where is it defined, and what does it look like?

Comment: can you show where you preparing this testDataSet might be there is no key TweetText in it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you pass through a list, but you want to use a dict. For it to work you have to use:

```
for key, value in dict_foo.items()
```

If you go through a list while it is a dict you will just have access to the key.